# How can I make two test buttons with TKinter run two functions independent of each other? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, python-3.7

So I have a GUI with two buttons and they run two different functions. But the problem is I can't run the second button unless the first button finish executing.

How can I make each button works independent of the other using python3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best developer, but essentially when you click on the button, the tkinter window waits for the command to finish. After it has finished, you then are able to click the other buttons.

One way that I have come around this is by using threads, which is a tad bit complicated but easy to grasp once you understand the basics. You can find resources on threads in python [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Best of luck :)